# How to AWK multiple columns in bash

Tags: awk

I have this table below that has multiple columns. **What I want is to print first and the second column only**

this command below produces the below table:

```
kubectl get ing -n my-namespace 


firstcolumn          secondcolumn        third columns
1                    test                value
3                    test2               value
2                    test3               value
5                    test4               value
6                    test                value
```

expected output should be:

```
firstcolumn          secondcolumn        
1                    test                
3                    test2               
2                    test3               
5                    test4               
6                    test
```

this below command only `awk` the first column.

```
kubectl get ing -n my-namespace | awk '{ printf "%10s\n", $2 }'
```

how to `awk` both first and second columns?

Comment: so the value can contain space? for example, I see `third columns` with a space, can it occur on other columns too?

Comment: `awk '{ printf "%10s\n", $2 }'` does not print the 1st column, it prints the 2nd column (note the `$2` as opposed to `$1`). Given that `$2` means the `2`nd column, is it obvious now how to print the `1`st column too? If not - is that white space between your columns a single tab char or multiple blank chars or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. This will print same spaces what is present between your 1st and 2nd fields.

```
awk '{match($0,/ +/);print $1,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  match($0,/ +/)                             ##Usingawk match function which will match very first ALL spaces in current line.
  print $1,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$2      ##Now printing $1 then substring starting from RSTART to RLENGTH(which will have spaces in it) then 2nd field.
}
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

OR in case you are NOT worried about spacing(which I think you are worried about spacig) then you can simply do:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the first two columns using,
`kubectl get ing -n my-namespace | awk '{ print $1, $2}'`.
By default, awk takes space as a column separator.